# How to determine the convexity of multiple matrix variables function?

Tags: convex-analysis, machine-learning, operations-research, non-convex-optimization

This formula is :
$$f(W,V,B) =\|XW-V\|^2_F +\|Y-VB\|^2_F +\operatorname{tr}(V'LV) +2\operatorname{tr}(W'DW),$$
where $X$, $Y$ are constant matrices and $L$ is constant laplace matrix. Suppose $D$ is a constant diagonal matrix.

After @ A.Γ.'s suggestion, I modified the question. The original question is as follows:

Is the convexity of a function with a saddle point multivariate function plus a multivariate convex function necessarily non-convex?

Comment: The question is unclear. In your formula, the second term is neither saddle point nor convex function. Answering the question in the title: no, it may be convex, for example, $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $g(x,y)=y^2$ where $f+g$ is convex.

Comment: @ A.Γ.  Sorry, I don't know about this  knowledge about convex optimization, so the question is not rigorous enough.   why is this formula non-convex?